# HTTP Referer after 302 Redirect

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, http-referer, http-status-code-302

I am creating a website using Java servlets, and I have a page called LogIn. What I want to happen, is that once the user successfully fills out the login form, it returns them to the page that they were previously on.

Now this works fine with a GET or a POST from another page, because the previous page is stored in the Referer header. But when I redirect (302) to the LogIn page (from a page that a user cannot access because they are not logged in), the Referer header is null.

Is there any way to achieve what I want when the user is redirected to the LogIn page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't trust the referer header anyway since you're dependent on the browser whether it's been sent along. Rather supply it yourself based on the current request URI.

```
response.sendRedirect("login?from=" + URLEncoder.encode(request.getRequestURI(), "UTF-8"));
```

and then in the login form

```
<form action="login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="${param.from}">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and then in the login action

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("from"));
} else {
    request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown login");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

---

**Update**: or if you want to be parameter-less (as per your comment on other answer), (ab)use the session.

```
session.setAttribute("from", request.getRequestURI());
response.sendRedirect("login");
```

and then in the login action

```
response.sendRedirect((String) session.getAttribute("from"));
session.removeAttribute("from");
```

Comment: Ok, so GET parametres really are the only way to do it? We are trying to make the URLs very short and meaningful, so unfortunately this means no GET parametres.

Comment: I already updated the answer a sec after I saw your comment on other answer. F5 your browser.

Comment: Ah yes, session abuse. I think I might already use that somewhere, so I might as well use it here too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just append the current page as a GET parameter ie http://yoursite.com/login?redir=/topics so that in your auth servlet, if the user doesn't have the appropriate credentials, just take the current uri, append to the login url and redirect.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but with this particular site, we are trying to make the URLs very short and meaningful, so unfortunately this means no GET parametres.

Comment: Could you perhaps look at dropping a cookie or storing the vals in session? I don't like the solution, personally, but is plausible.

Comment: Yea, I think I might already use that somewhere, so quite a plausible solution. Thanks!